# Split and remove entire line from string

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

I have some text file that looks like this:

```
blah blah 
2131232 SPLIT
fdsfdsf dfds
fds fdsdf 
fdsf fds
3423423 SPLIT
dsf 324 fdsr
3243 fsdf 3wrfs
543534 SPLIT
```

If I do this: `contentOfThatFile.split('SPLIT')` I am left with the the numbers at the beginning of the file. Is there anyway to use `split()` with removing the ENTIRE line that is being split on? So that the output would be:

```
blah blah 

fdsfdsf dfds
fds fdsdf 
fdsf fds

dsf 324 fdsr
3243 fsdf 3wrfs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

foo = re.split('.* SPLIT',x)
print(foo)
```

For your specific example, including transforming into a list vs keeping it as a string (whatever your preference may be), here is a more detailed snippet:

```
words = """blah blah 
           2131232 SPLIT
           fdsfdsf dfds
           fds fdsdf 
           fdsf fds
           3423423 SPLIT
           dsf 324 fdsr
           3243 fsdf 3wrfs
           543534 SPLIT"""

import re
import itertools

foo =  re.split('.* SPLIT\n*',words)
re_joined = ''.join(foo).strip()
re_split = re_joined.split('\n')

print(re_joined)
print(re_split)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I was looking for a wild card option. Thank you! For anyone searching in the future, `x` is the string you are doing the operation on.

Answer (score 2):

The below writes a new file "newfile.txt" from source file "texttosplit.txt" excluding any lines in the file that contain "SPLIT."

```
with open('texttosplit.txt') as fo:
    for line in fo:
        if "SPLIT" in line:
            line=""
        newfile=open("newfile.txt",'a')
        newfile.write(line)
        newfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Split by newline instead:

```
contentOfThatFile.split('\n')
```

Then iterate through each line and ignore all the ones with SPLIT in it:

```
[line if 'SPLIT' not in line else '\n' for line in contentOfThatFile.split('\n')]
```

This will replace every line in the file that has `SPLIT` in it with a new line.